# Trouble writing cache-validator for Google Fonts resources

Tags: .htaccess, caching, http-headers, cache-control

I am using a couple of Google fonts in my site and as recommended by Google, this is how I have them declared in my HTML `<head></head>` section:

```
   <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

A performance test over at GTmetrix recommends this:

> The following resources are missing a cache validator. Resources that
>   do not specify a cache validator cannot be refreshed efficiently.
>   Specify a Last-Modified or ETag header to enable cache validation for
>   the following resources:
>
> ```
> https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700
> https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald
> ```

My question is, how do I accomplish this? I have all **mod_expires** and **Cache-Control** duly included in my `.htaccess` for all file extensions I could think of, including woff, ttf, etc. But since the resources in question don't have an explicit extension as shown in the `<link>` tags, how do I write a **Cache-Control** and **mod_expires** entry for them?

Answer (score 1):

> > Specify a Last-Modified or ETag header [...]
> >
> > for the following resources:
> >     https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald
>
> My question is, how do I accomplish this?

You can't. Only the operator of `googleapis.com` (namely, Google) can control the headers of those resources. This reduces your control, but means that Google is responsible for the load of repeated requests.

> the resources in question don't have an explicit extension as shown in the `<link>` tags

Currently, `curl -i 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald'` includes:

```
Cache-Control: private, max-age=86400
```

That means a browser should only request another copy after a day.

The response payload is only 230 bytes (less than half the size of its HTTP/1.1 headers). At that size, [a conditional request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33682533/what-makes-conditional-gets-conditional-if-the-resource-is-obtained-in-the-ini) (`Last-Modified` or `ETag`) is no quicker than sending the payload again.

Those cache headers are out of your control and are well-chosen for these resources. `googleapis.com` knows what it's doing; the performance test you're running is offering general advice that doesn't apply well in this case.